# solution to a nonlinear equation

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Is there a simple way of solving system of nonlinear equations given by

$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_{ij} x_j}{1+\sum_{k=1}^J a_{ik}x_k} = c_j $

where $a_{ij}$ and $c_j$ are constants. In other words, is there a change of variable method that makes solving this system numerically tractable than current specification?

Answer (score 0):

These equations in rational functions correspond to a system of polynomial equations, which
in general will "reduce" to a hellishly complicated polynomial in one variable.  So you're not likely to get anywhere looking for closed-form solutions.  Have you tried multivariate Newton-type numerical methods with the system as given?

Comment: Thanks. Yes and it seems that the newton type of methods for this specific example is not very robust (I am not very informed about the technical issues, just read it somewhere) and I was hoping to get a more reliable technique.